# IF statement to copy across and fill down selected Excel column values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Is there an easy way to copy down the highlighted yellow cells in Column D of embedded picture into Column E?  I want to copy down the yellow highlighted cells until another yellow highlighted cell appears, then copy down that yellow cell, etc.

[image: To show what is to be copied down]

Data sample, including some of the output required, for test purposes:

```
    D           E            F
Row Labels                 Min of PRICE
283200-1005    283200-1005    325
COMPANY63      283200-1005    325
COMPANY60      283200-1005    1000
COMPANY59      283200-1005    2250
COMPANY35      283200-1005    2495
COMPANY4       283200-1005    2750
COMPANY11      283200-1005    3200
321-400-703-0  321-400-703-0  1000
COMPANY60      321-400-703-0  1000
COMPANY64      321-400-703-0  1145
COMPANY42      321-400-703-0  2800
COMPANY11      321-400-703-0  3275
4063-16082-3                  1000
COMPANY8                      1000
COMPANY24                     1800
COMPANY4                      2750
COMPANY11                     3200
COMPANY51                     3481
COMPANY14                     4350
Grand Total                   325
```

Comment: You can try selecting the column, `Data->Filter->Filter By Color`. Copy and paste somewhere, remove the filter, then cut and paste into column E. p.s. I dont see the VBA here.

Comment: p.s. I dont see the VBA *tag* here. If you're looking for a VBA solution, please add the `VBA` and `Excel-VBA` tags.

Comment: I don't see yellow in your example. Nor do I see any VBA. Theoretically this is easily solved by writing a VBA script that iterates down column D cells and checks their color highlight for yellow. If it is yellow, and different than the previous yellow cell, store and copy to column E. etc

Comment: Thanks. And sorry, the yellow is only the numbers in Column D - 283200-1005, 321-400-703-0, 4063-16082-3. Wanting to copy those parts down like I have in column E. I have around 90K lines :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is, assuming `Row Labels` is in D3, in E4 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(D4)*1),D4,E3)
```